# CommandButton cannot get into action method in dataTable

Tags: jsf, datatable, commandbutton

I am new to JSF, I couldn't sort it out. Any prompt explanation is appreciated.
My case is fairly simple, I have a `<h:dataTable>` display a list of query result, I want to get the selected row and trigger a method in my controller for further operation (like modify or delete). If I put commandButton inside the dataTable, as the `doSth2`, it doesn't get into the action method doSth() in MyController class, but if I move the button outside the dataTable, like the `doSth1`, it works perfectly. Can anyone explain why there is such a difference.

BTW, how can I get the active selected row in the dataTable and pass it to the action method. Actually I read some threads which show that you can pass the row data by `action="#{myController.doSth(_tran)}"`. First this doesn't work in my case, I don't like the `doSth2` button to be displayed in every row of the table either. Thanks a lot.

```
    <h:form id="form1">
        <p>
            <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                <h:commandButton id="otherButton" .../>
                <h:commandButton id="doSth1" value="doSth1" styleClass="pushbutton" 
                    action="#{myController.doSth}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p>
    </h:form>
    ...
    <h:form id="form2">
        <h:dataTable var="_tran" value="#{trans}" rendered="#{not empty trans}" styleClass="simpletablestyle">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">col1</f:facet>
                #{_tran.id}
            </h:column>
            ...
            <h:column>
                    <h:commandButton id="doSth2" value="doSth2" styleClass="pushbutton"
                        action="#{myController.doSth}"/>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: What type of Scope you are using?

Comment: Your problem is covered by points 4 and/or 5 of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked

Comment: @BalusC I changed my controller from `@Model` which include `@RequestScoped` to `@ManagedBean @ViewScoped`, now it works. But I don't know why the `@RequestScoped` will cause this issue. And also can you show me how to get the active selected row by not inserting a button/link in each row?

Comment: Both CDI and JSF have their own bean scopes from reqeust, session, application etc., like `@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped` and `@javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped`, but JSF has ViewScoped which CDI doesn't have. What's the difference between the 2 set of scope annotation?